# How can you animate a roll of tablecloth flying out of the backpack?

Tags: animation, modifiers, physics, cloth-simulation, vertex-weights

How can you animate a roll of tablecloth flying out of the backpack?

After the flight it should be laid out on the table. I'm trying to combine these two tutorials, you can see at the link, but it doesn't work.

How can I solve this?

https://youtu.be/rngJtuoC88c?si=V-5wCd0hhMeju1jn

https://youtu.be/g_JmL9I50Io?si=vzASST2P9PZRQjh9

[image: table, backpack, roll, vertex map field(cube)]

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create the tablecloth object (1), subdivide it, give it a *Curve* modifier with a spiral (2) as *Curve Object*, select all its vertices and assign them to a vertex group, give it a *Vertex Weight Proximity* modifier.

In this *Vertex Weight Proximity* modifier select the vertex group as *Vertex Group*,  select object 3 as *Target Object* (this is a subdivided plane that you duplicate on Z), select *Proximity Mode > Geometry* and tweak the *Lowest* and *Highest* values.

Give a *Cloth* simulation to your tablecloth with the vertex group as *Pin Group*, enable *Self Collisions*.

Parent the tablecloth and the spiral to the vertex weight proximity object (3). Create a table object (4) and give it a *Collision* simulation:

[image]

Object 3 is the *Vertex Weight Proximity* object, is a subidivided plane that is duplicated on Z:

[image]

The tablecloth modifier settings:

[image]

Keyframe the location of the vertex weight proximity object (3) and of the tablecloth:

[image]

Comment: what that object 3(planes across Z) does? If i need cube as a target object of weight? No? Please can you give a more detailed answer, with screenshots!

Comment: See my edit, it's a subdivided plane that is duplicated on Z

Comment: ooh, its like an one object! I got it. So its better than doing just one cube with no subdivide?

Comment: Yes because the vertices will be taken into account by the Vertex Weight Proximity modifier, I've just released a tutorial on your question but it's in french, I hope it helps to understand? https://youtu.be/NDOrOx6wcI8

Comment: Woow! Thanks! Its really helped!